# Why is this simple C tic-tac-toe program "forgetting" the value at position [0][0] in an array, but works fine for everything else?

Tags: c

The format for inserting a move is xYZ, where x is either 'o' or 'x', Y is the line number and Z is the column number.

If you try to play x11 and then o11, for example, it will correctly point out that it's an invalid play since (1,1) is already occupied. It works for every position BUT (0,0), where for some reason it lets you keep playing the same move over and over.

I also know that it draws the board properly after your move, so if you play o00 it will show a O at (0,0), but then it will forget that position come next turn.

Example: http://image.prntscr.com/image/e002bb6db5da4c7b823bf9bcac7af5eb.png

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int board[3][3] = { 0 };
    int i, j, linha, coluna, valido, run = 1;
    char comando[3], jogador, ultimo_jogador;
    while (run) {
        //recebe o comando para executar esse turno
        valido = 0;
        do {
            printf("Digite a jogada: ");
            scanf(" %3[^\n]", comando);
            jogador = comando[0];
            linha = comando[1] - 48;
            coluna = comando[2] - 48;
            if ((jogador == 'x' || jogador == 'o') && jogador != ultimo_jogador && board[linha][coluna] == 0) {
                if (jogador == 'x')
                    board[linha][coluna] = 1;
                else if (jogador == 'o')
                    board[linha][coluna] = 2;
                ultimo_jogador = jogador;
                valido = 1;
            }
            else {
                printf("Comando inválido\n");
            }
        } while (!valido);

        //desenha o tabuleiro do jogo
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (i == 0 && j == 0)
                    printf("Value at 0,0: %d\n", board[i][j]);
                if (board[i][j] == 0) {
                    printf("_|");
                }
                else if (board[i][j] == 1) {
                    printf("X|");
                }
                else if (board[i][j] == 2) {
                    printf("O|");
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: works for me: `Digite a jogada: x00
Comando invßlido
Digite a jogada: o00
Comando invßlido` (after having successfully put something in 0x0). Can you post the traces of execution? (please [edit] your question, don't comment with the traces)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It does? Interesting. Then it might be an environment issue for some reason, since I'm running this code on Windows compiled by mingw. Though I can't say I can see why something like this wouldn't work on windows.

Comment: I use windows too, with some professional gcc, not too far from mingw. Post your traces, we'll see clearer.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre look the link of his image

Comment: @Stargateur right! okay you have a problem here. Out of the blue: insert parentheses here: `(jogador != ultimo_jogador) && (board[linha][coluna] == 0)`. I know it sounds stupid, but it cannot harm the code.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I added the parentheses, but it's still the same. I apologize, but I have to look up how to perform a trace of execution as instructed.

Comment: what would be interesting would be to print `board[linha][coluna]` and line & column before the test.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre like this? http://image.prntscr.com/image/78b09427e0784aa585a6912e09f9fd55.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just had a visit of *undefined behaviour* AKA UB.

I finally found an explanation:

You define `comando` with a size of 3, but when scanning the string, you're entering 3 chars but you miss the space for the *string termination*.

In our tests, the value overwrites some local variable like `i` or `j`, which is not noticeable since they're initialized afterwards and each time, but your compiler seem to locate the `board` memory just after the `comando` buffer (the compiler can do whatever it pleases with local variable addresses)

The result is that you're overwriting the first cell each time you input your value.

Solution: do this:

```
char comando[4];
```

Comment: Yes, that was indeed the case. I had somehow completely forgotten about the termination byte, and worse yet I didn't realize that it could result in something like this. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: in those situations, debugging + memory watch is helpful.